Using classes annotated with @IsTest in actual code
Consider this code -
HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
httpRequest.setEndpoint('callout:' + MyConstants.NAMED_CREDENTIAL + '/v1/somepath');
httpRequest.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
httpRequest.setMethod('POST');
httpRequest.setBody(String.join(requestParams, '&'));

HttpResponse rawHttpResponse = new Http().send(httpRequest);

The MyConstants is annotated with @IsTest like this -
@IsTest
public class MyConstants {

    public static final String NAMED_CREDENTIAL = 'Named_Cred';
}

I can confirm that this code works, even with the @IsTest annotation on the constants class, and the test class for the above code also does not seem to cause any problems.
Question -
Is this the correct thing to do, or do I risk breaking tests in the future?

Why is your constants class marked as @IsTest?

Correct - no, Breaking tests - depends. Best practice is for test classes to be private, one reason for doing so is to avoid accidental/broken dependency scenarios such as yours.

You could move the literal named credential into Custom Metadata

The intention is that I want to try this out. An apex class only with String constants, so why not mark it @IsTest so that we can avoid worrying about code coverage on that one.

Observation - Any public constants in a class marked IsTest can be used successfully in test and non-test classes. The code compiles and runs fine. However, public methods inside test classes can only be CALLED from the test code. Calling a test method from a non-test class compiles, but DOES NOT execute.
